# configure: error: "could not find the zlib libaray." in Bash

Tags: software-installation, configure

I am trying to install a program "bfast" on my linux system but i am getting following errors:

OS= CentOS

**Package libdv-devel-1.0.0-17.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version**

**Package glibc-devel-2.17-106.el7_2.1.i686 already installed and latest version**

Bfast:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/bfast/files/latest/download

sh autogen.sh

./configure

```
**fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git**
checking bzlib.h usability... yes
checking bzlib.h presence... yes
checking for bzlib.h... yes
**checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no**
**checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no**
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... no
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
**checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... no
checking for pow in -lm... no
checking for gzread in -lz... no
configure: error: "could not find the zlib libaray."**
```

However, I already installed prerequisite packages for this.

```
whereis zlib
**zlib: /usr/include/zlib.h** /usr/share/man/man3/zlib.3.g

whereis bzip2
**bzip2: /usr/bin/bzip2** /usr/share/man/man1/bzip2.1.gz
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us where we can find this `bfast` so we can try; ii) show us the exact command your ran that produced these errors and iii) tell us what operating system (if Linux, which distribution as well) you are using.

Comment: You need to install the *development* packages, usually called `foo-devel` or similar. Or you might be trying to build for the wrong architecture.

Comment: @vonbrand I suggest you post this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the development packages, usually called `foo-devel` or similar. Or you might be trying to build for the wrong architecture.

Comment: I already installed group of development packages and their libraries.

#yum groupinstall 'Development Tools' 'Development Libraries'

#yum install zlib-devel libyaml-devel openssl-devel gdbm-devel readline-devel ncurses-devel libffi-devel curl git openssh-server redis libxml2-devel libxslt-devel libcurl-devel libicu-devel python

What else need to install ?? becasue error is same.??

Comment: Its done, i installed package and now its fine. Actually i installed 32 bit before but now its ok.
#yum install bzip2-devel
thank by the way